# Bedeutung von "Gestatten,..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> **Gestatten**, mein Name ist Cox (Name eines Romans)
>   Mein Erfolg hat viele Väter. **Gestatten**, der Papst /*Aus einem aufklärenden Video über das HIV-Virus*/

Was möchte der Sprecher dabei ausdrücken?

Comment: Man könnte beinahe den Eindruck haben, der Fragesteller hätte sich nicht der Mühe unterzogen, "gestatten" in einem Wörterbuch nachzuschlagen.

Comment: I believe that "gestatten" here as a meaning in context. To improve the question, I would give the normal meaning, and then ask why that particular meaning doesn't seem to fit the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gestatten" als solches ist, in diesem Zusammenhang, die etwas veraltete Kurzform von "Gestatten Sie, dass ich mich (oder die Person neben mir) Ihnen vorstelle." Gestatten ist allgemein eine Höflichkeitsform von "Erlauben".

Im [Video](https://youtu.be/U1Vao7nVY5Y) soll wahrscheinlich zum Ausdruck gebracht werden, dass die Verbreitung von HIV durch die Verhütungsverbote der katholischen Kirche und des Papsts als ihr Oberhaupt die Verbreitung begünstigten. Der Papst wird hier vom Sprecher bzw. Virus als einer der Väter des Erfolgs des Viruses dem Zuschauer "präsentiert".

Comment: "... des Erfolgs gegen den Virus ..."?

Comment: @help-info.de: eben gerade nicht gegen den Virus.

Comment: @help-info.de https://youtu.be/U1Vao7nVY5Y?t=26s

Comment: @Alexander - danke für die YouTube URL

Answer (score 1):

(1) Derjenige stellt sich in (veralteter) höflicher Weise z.B. auch durch Ziehen des Hutes jemandem vor, um ein Gespräch zu beginnen bzw. aufzubauen.

(2) Derjenige nimmt sich in förmlicher Weise die - gegebenenfalls nicht erwünschte - Freiheit etwas zu tun oder zu lassen.

> Gestatten, ich trete mal [in den Raum] ein.
>
> Gestatten, ich werde ich die Sitzung jetzt verlassen.

Als Synonym ist denkbar:

sich erlauben, sich gönnen, sich zubilligen, dulden, einräumen, zulassen